# loading traineddata for tesseract-android-tools (android)

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I am working on android app.
What I need is directly path to traineddata file (to init tesseract).
Look like best option is to set the resource in raw.

I am getting resource ID this way (file name is : deu.traineddata):

```
int rID = resources.getIdentifier("deu", "raw", "my.code.package");
```

OK, 'rID' > 0, now getting Stream  :

```
InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(rID);
```

ok, 'is' != null.
But now getting problem ,by reading 'is' IOException has been throw, with no stack trace  :

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(bytes);
```

I try also to read file from asset , but is the same problem by reading from InputStream.
What i'am doing wrong, ist there any other way to get the resource path ?
thanx
andrej

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the native code in tesseract-android-tools (under jni), you will see that the library will access a file.  I am in the same boat at the moment. After some digging, my plan is to store the traineddata file as a resource along with the project, and write to the private file on load.

The pseudo code is something like this:

on load, check for private file, 
if it doesn't exist, load the traineddata from raw dir and write to the private file.
initialize tesseract with the private file.

ref:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Cheers

Comment: after some try didn't work, so I download traineddata directly from tesseract server.Thanx any way.